# Show partial view based on parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the process of updating a C# MVC 2.0 application!

I have a view “Signup” and another view “ForgotPassword”.

Each view have a  with a submit button.

Each form is submitted to the ***same*** Controller but to two different ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Signup(SignupModel signupModel)
{…}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ForgotPwd(ForgotPasswordModel forgotPasswordModel)
{…}
```

Upon completion my goal is to redirect the user to a “thankyou” page but based on where the user is coming from (either Signup or ForgotPassword) I wish to display a particular message (or a different UI).

Inside the same Controller, I created a “Thankyou” ActionResult:

```
public ViewResult Thankyou() 
{
    return View(); 
}
```

I was thinking of adding a **parameter** to my Thankyou() method which would allow me to know where the user is coming from (Signup or ForgotPwd). From there, make the “thankyou” page display the appropriate UI/message.

I’m looking for a clean and simple solution.

Should I create two View User Controls and show the appropriate one based on the parameter being passed?

In addition, instead of having an “ActionResult” for my Thankyou() method couldn’t I use a “PartialViewResult” ?

---

EDIT:
I was actually considering something along those lines…

Where `ThankyouType` is an Enum.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Signup(SignupModel signupModel)
{
    //Validation code...
    return View("Thankyou", ThankyouType.SignupDone);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordModel forgotPasswordModel)
{
    //Validation code...
    return View("Thankyou", ThankyouType.ForgotPasswordDone);
}
```

And then have my “Thankyou” ViewResult like this:

```
public ViewResult Thankyou(ThankyouType type) 
{ 
    return View(type); 
}
```

Doesn’t seem like I can create a strongly typed view based on Enum (unless I’m wrong).

Perhaps I’ll read more on PartialViewResults and/or find examples…but then again, I could be completely wrong.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I believe you can't do `return View("Thankyou", ThankyouType.ForgotPasswordDone);`, but you can do `return View("Thankyou", new{type = ThankyouType.ForgotPasswordDone});`

Comment: I’ve just tested it and it appears to be possible…then only thing is that placing a break point in my Thankyou() method *never* gets hit. I’ll you sample a try.

Comment: Oh, I'd just assumed your problem was it was reaching your thankyou result with a null ThankYouType. I was just showing how to pass a ThankYouType object around your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally give the ThankYou view a model that has the message you want to display, and have your two controller actions render the ThankYou view directly on success rather than calling a ThankYou action.

However, if you're sure you want a redirect, you may consider using the `TempData` collection to store a message or a key of some kind. The ThankYou controller can then retrieve this value and pass it to the View. This situation is what `TempData` was made for.

#### Edit

There's no reason you shouldn't be able to use an enum value as your model type, but if that gives you trouble you should at least be able to create a model type that has an enum property on it.

The strategy of sending the ThankYouType as part of the redirect request would work just fine, if that's what you prefer. The only potential downside is that it would look like this in the URL:

```
http://domain.com/controller/ThankYou?type=ForgotPasswordDone
```

I have no real arguments against it. There are lots of options. Use the one that feels best to you.

Comment: If I make my two ActionResult directly display the « Thankyou » view upon success, will I have any issues if the users hit the refresh button (F5) in their browsers? Will it re-submit the form?

Comment: @Vlince: Yes. Assuming you're `POST`ing the data, their browser would first warn them that they are re-posting the information and might perform an action twice. If they tell the browser to go ahead, then it would allow them to re-post the same data. If you redirect them to a separate page, and they click the Back button you might have similar problems depending on your caching directives. If they click Back and then refresh, you'd have the same problem regardless of the cache settings.

Comment: Thanks Warrior! And yes, I am POSTing the data.

I’ve tried the *redirect* approach (to avoid the F5 issue) 
return RedirectToAction("Thankyou", "Home"); 

But the problem I seem to have is that I can’t pass an additional parameter while using RedirectToAction.

Comment: @Vlince: Oh, is that all? Try `return RedirectToAction("ThankYou", "Home", new { type = ThankyouType.ForgotPasswordDone });`

Comment: I understand the potential downside but so far, this seems to be the lesser of two evils as I wouldn’t want the users to accidently (or not) hit F5.

Unless of course, I use the TempData approach.

Since I create the views from VS, Right-click—add view, in the strongly type dropdown I couldn’t see my Enum even if it is public. I’ve compiled just to make sure but still couldn’t select it. Hence why I believed you couldn’t create a strongly typed view based on Enums

Comment: @Vlince: One other strategy that we haven't mentioned would be to submit the form via AJAX. That would make it much easier to avoid a double-post through user error, but it would require a little javascript on the client side.